# How can I join a table with itself with NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have this table (test):

```
+----+---------+-----+---+
| ID |  Name   |  A  | B |
+----+---------+-----+---+
|  1 | Steve   | 200 | 0 |
|  2 | Steve   | 200 | 1 |
|  5 | James   |  90 | 0 |
|  4 | James   |  50 | 1 |
|  3 | Warrick | 100 | 1 |
+----+---------+-----+---+
```

and this SQL query:

```
SELECT one.Name as Name, one.A as one_value, zero.A as zero_value 
FROM test one LEFT JOIN test zero ON one.Name = zero.Name AND one.A <> zero.A
WHERE zero.B = 0 AND one.B = 1
```

which returns:

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| Name  | one_value | zero_value |
+-------+-----------+------------+
| James |        50 |         90 |
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

But what I want is when a record exists only with B = 1 that it is included in the response with a NULL value or something in the zero_value column, like this:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
|  Name   | one_value | zero_value |
+---------+-----------+------------+
| James   |        50 | 90         |
| Warrick |       100 | NULL       |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

How can I do this?

Edit:

I worked it out:

```
SELECT one.Name, one.A, zero.A
FROM test one LEFT JOIN test zero ON one.Name = zero.Name AND ( zero.B = 0 OR zero.B is NULL )
WHERE ( one.A <> zero.A OR zero.A is null )
```

Comment: Try this `SELECT one.Name as Name, one.A as one_value, zero.A as zero_value FROM test one JOIN test zero ON one.Name = zero.Name 
AND one.A <> zero.A 
WHERE (zero.B = 0 OR zero.B IS NULL)  AND ( one.B = 1 OR OR one.B IS NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

Because of the left join the value of `zero.B` may be `NULL`, so you need to extend the `WHERE` condition:

```
WHERE one.B=1 AND (zero.B IS NULL OR zero.B = 0)
```

#### Update

You should also move the score condition down into WHERE:

```
WHERE one.B=1 AND (zero.B IS NULL OR zero.B = 0)
    AND (zero.A IS NULL OR one.A <> zero.A)
```

Comment: This returns an unwanted row with Steve as well, with one_value = 200 and zero_value = NULL.

Comment: @user3341880 Hmm yeah, that's a different kind of problem, though .. related to your join condition; moving the condition on score to the WHERE would fix that.

Comment: Not sure I follow. If I'm using the incorrect join could you please correct me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
select Name ,
       (case when B= 0 Then A else null) as zero_value,
       (case when B= 1 Then A else null) as one_value
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` is a good thing here, this is what you want :

```
SELECT
    one.Name
    ,one.A as one_value
    , zero.A as zero_value 
FROM test one
    LEFT JOIN test zero
        on one.Name = zero.Name
        and zero.B = 0
where one.B = 1
```

Perhaps you want to handle when record exists only with B = 0 that it is included in the response with a NULL value in the one_value column in same time :

```
SELECT
   test.Name
   , one.A as one_value
   , zero.A as zero_value 
FROM 
    (   SELECT Name
        FROM test
        GROUP BY Name) test
    LEFT JOIN test one
        on test.Name = one.Name
        and one.B = 1
    LEFT JOIN test zero
        on test.Name = zero.Name
        and zero.B = 0
```

[Here is a demo for both queries :)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a67717/11)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6332a/7/0

### Try thiz query that give exact result for u

`SELECT Test.nme,
one.A AS one_value,
zero.A AS zero_value
FROM(SELECT  name AS nme FROM test WHERE name NOT in( SELECT one.Name FROM test one LEFT JOIN test zero ON (one.Name = zero.Name AND one.A=zero.A)
WHERE zero.B=0 AND one.B=1)GROUP BY name)Test
LEFT JOIN test one ON test.nme=one.Name AND one.B=1
LEFT JOIN test zero ON test.nme=zero.Name AND zero.B=0;`

Comment: This exacty what I don't want to see when I watch at SQL query, you have 2 subquery (perfomance killer) and 1 not in (distinct is not good be required here). This is not readable, scalable and maintainable. Are you really oracle certified?

Comment: Haha ok, cause of your avatar icon ^^ Have a look on my answer, to see how to avoid subquery :)